# find all posts of user friend list by linq

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have 2 tables ( `tblPosts` , `tblFriends` ) like bellow tables :

```
tblPost:
--------
PostID         ( nvarchar )
PostValue      ( nvarchar )
PostSender     ( nvarchar )
```

'
'

```
tblFriends:
------------
ID             ( int )
User1          ( nvarchar )
User2          ( nvarchar )
```

now my question is , how can I find all posts of `user1` friends by LINQ ?

Comment: What are the types of the tables? What field relates `tblFriends` to `tblPost`?

Comment: the db is ms sql

Answer (score 0):

First, find the friends of `user1`:

```
var friends = from f in tblFriends
              where f.User1 == user1
              select f.User2;
```

Then find all the posts sent by those friends:

```
var friendsPosts = from p in tblPost
                   where friends.Contains(p.PostSender)
                   select p;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim q = From fr In db.tblFriends, post In db.tblPosts
                Where fr.User1 = Username And post.Username = fr.User2
                Order By post.RegDate Descending
                Select post
```

Comment: But now I have another problem ! , How can I get just one post of each friend not all posts of each friend

Comment: If you just want the first of these posts, you can do this after
`q.First()`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not completed. So write clearly with a relationship of the table and proper format of the output. If you want all posts of belonging user1 then try the following query.

```
     var val = (from a in tblPost
                 join b in tblFriends on a.PostSender equals b.User1
                 select a).ToList();
```